# How do I get Spring to use https?

Tags: spring-security

in the most basic sense, what library's, xml entries, tags do I need to setup a secure http page (Using Spring)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to configure your server to support HTTPS, which means getting or generating a certificate and installing it into the certificate store.  Here's a quick start on how to configure SSL with Tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Once you have the server listening on a port for https traffic, you can configure your application with just a couple of modifications to your existing spring security xml configuration as noted here http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-requires-channel

Comment: Awesome thanks for the response digitaljoel!